# How to sync a LineRenderer in a multiplayer game?

Tags: multiplayer, synchronization, unity-networking, unet

After a lot of searching online, I have come here as a last resort for my problem.

The question says it all. How to sync a LineRenderer?

One answer I found was to use a ClientRpc. I tried it with no effect.

Below is the snippet of my code,

```
    IEnumerator laserBeam()// This is called through another method on the click of a button
        {
            Beam = GetComponent<LineRenderer> ();
            Beam.SetVertexCount (2);
            Beam.material = BeamMaterial;
            Beam.SetWidth (0.07f, 0.07f);
            Beam.enabled = true;
            Beam.SetPosition (0, gameObject.transform.position);
            Beam.SetPosition (1, target.position);
            RpcDrawLines (gameObject, target.position, true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.0f);
            Beam.enabled = false;
            RpcDrawLines (gameObject, target.position, false);
        }

    [ClientRpc]
    public void RpcDrawLines(GameObject start, Vector3 end, bool isOn)
    {
        LineRenderer beam = start.GetComponent<LineRenderer> ();
        if (isOn) {
            beam.SetVertexCount (2);
            beam.material = BeamMaterial;
            beam.SetWidth (0.07f, 0.07f);
            beam.enabled = true;
            beam.SetPosition (0, start.transform.position);
            beam.SetPosition (1, end);
        } 
        else 
            {
                beam.enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

So, this is the code. Works fine on the Server but no effect in the client. I know I am doing something wrong in the client rpc. But I have no idea what it is. Any way of help would be appreciated. Thanks

**Note: I am using UNET**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. I solved it. I was an utter idiot to not think about using `[SyncVar]`.

Anyways, here's the solution,

```
 [SyncVar (hook = "OnBeamActive")]
 public bool isBeam = false;
```

Add this variable and set it to true on button press,

```
 isBeam = true; // set this to false when you want to disable the beam
```

Then define OnBeamActive as below,

```
 public void OnBeamActive(bool isOn)
    {
        Beam = GetComponent<LineRenderer> (); // LineRenderer has to be attached to the object to which this script is attached to
        if (!isOn)
           { // If "isOn" is false, you could disable "Beam" here using Beam.enabled = false
            return; 
           }
        isBeam = isOn;
        Beam.SetVertexCount (2);
        Beam.material = BeamMaterial;
        Beam.SetWidth (0.07f, 0.07f);
        Beam.enabled = true;
        Beam.SetPosition (0, transform.position);
        Beam.SetPosition (1, target.position);//target is a Transform referring to the end point of the beam/line. Initialize it the way you want
        }
```

So, that's it. Make this a part of your script from where you want the line/laser beam to start from. Also, make sure you attach a LineRenderer component to this object.